# 'not a graph obect' error when performing degree() from igraph package

Tags: r, igraph

Since I need normalized scores, I wanted to call the `degree()` function on my adjacency matrix I got from a text file I loaded into R using `read.delim`. That went perfectly fine with the `sna` package.

When I run

```
K3_T2_ACAD <- diag.remove(read.delim("K3_T2_ACAD.txt", header = TRUE, 
                                      sep = "\t", row.names = 1), remove.val=0)
```

and then

```
K3_T2_ACAD_indeg <- degree(K3_T2_ACAD, g=1, nodes=NULL, gmode="digraph", 
                           diag=FALSE, tmaxdev=FALSE, cmode="indegree")
```

it works!

I tried detaching the `sna` functions because I thought that was the problem. However, when I run the igraph `degree()` function, it does not work:

```
K3_T2_ACAD_indeg2 <- degree(K3_T2_ACAD, mode ="in", loops = FALSE, normalized = TRUE)
```

returns

> Error in degree(K3_T2_ACAD, mode = "in", loops = FALSE, normalized =
>   TRUE) : Not a graph object

The first column and row each contain the participant codes. Is it possible, that `igraph` cannot work with that, whereas `sna` can?

Comment: Please check out [how to make a reproducible question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for tips to improve your post. If we can't run some code and get the same error as you, it's hard to help you.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how I should do that in this case

Answer (score 1):

The `sna` package uses adjacency matrices, `igraph` does not not. You need to create an igraph object to work on. See e.g. http://igraph.org/r/doc/aaa-igraph-package.html